# Simple Java proxy server - google search error

Tags: java, http, proxy

I've written simple HTTP proxy server everything works except google search, Im reciving "net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" error in google chrome, and "Connection closed by remote server" in Opera. I don't have anymore ideas how to solve it. Could you help me?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class Server <Parametr>{

private Calendar current;
private DateFormat dformat;
private int localport = 0;
private int remoteport = 80;
private String remoteAddress = "127.0.0.1";
private Proxy proxy; 
private ServerSocketChannel servsocketchannel; 
private boolean local = false;

public Server(int port){
    setServerPort(port);
    openServerPort();
    checkAndSetRemoteProxyServer();
    dformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    current = Calendar.getInstance();   
    createServerSocketAndTalk();
}

public void setServerPort(int port){
    this.localport = port;
}

public void setProxyAddressAndPort(int port, String address){
    this.remoteport = port;
    this.remoteAddress = address;
}

public void openServerPort(){
    try {
        servsocketchannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        servsocketchannel.socket().bind(new java.net.InetSocketAddress(localport));
    } catch (BindException exc) {
        System.out.println("Server isn't started, local port is blocked or used, check firewall or set new port");

    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Server isn't started, local port is blocked or used, check firewall or set new port");
    }
}

public void checkAndSetRemoteProxyServer(){
    boolean ERROR = false;
    Socket proxysocketchannel = null;
    try {
        proxysocketchannel = new Socket(remoteAddress, remoteport);     
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) { 
        System.out.println("Proxy server address is probably offline, please provide new server address --- RUNNING LOCAL PROXY MODE");
        ERROR = true;
    } catch (IOException exc) {         
        System.out.println("Connecting to the proxy server failed, please review address and port --- RUNNING LOCAL PROXY MODE");
        ERROR = true;
    }   

    if(!ERROR){
        System.out.println("Proxy state - online");
        proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(remoteAddress, remoteport)); 
        System.out.println("Initialization successful - waiting for clients ");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Problem with proxy connection, check your settings or set new proxy address --- RUNNING LOCAL PROXY MODE");
        System.out.println("Proxy local mode initialization successful - waiting for clients ");
        local = true;
    }               
}

    public void createServerSocketAndTalk(){        
        try {
            while(servsocketchannel.isOpen()){              
                Runnable r = new ClientHandler(servsocketchannel.accept());
                Thread t = new Thread(r);
                t.start();              
            }
        }catch(NotYetBoundException exc){
            System.out.println("Server not started local port is already used, please choose new local port");      
        }catch (AsynchronousCloseException ex) {
            System.out.println("Server Closed");
        }
        catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

 class ClientHandler implements Runnable{

        SocketChannel client = null;

        private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 32768;

        public ClientHandler(SocketChannel client){
            this.client = client;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            letsTalk();
            try {
                this.finalize();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }           

        public void letsTalk(){

                while(true){

                        if(client.socket().isClosed()){
                            break;
                        }

                        BufferedReader clientin = null;
                        DataOutputStream clientout = null;                      

                        try {
                            clientin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.socket().getInputStream()));                         
                            clientout = new DataOutputStream(client.socket().getOutputStream());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            System.out.println("Error with client connection");                         
                            break;                      
                        }                          

                           String inputline;
                           String url = "";

                           try {
                            while((inputline = clientin.readLine()) != null){
                                    System.out.println(inputline);
                                   StringTokenizer readerclient = new StringTokenizer(inputline);
                                   if(readerclient.nextToken().equals("GET")){                                     
                                      url = readerclient.nextToken();
                                      System.out.println("Requested URL:  " + url);
                                      break;
                                   }        
                                   if(readerclient.nextToken().equals("POST")){
                                       System.out.println("POST");
                                   }
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            System.out.println("URL REQUEST ERROR");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (NullPointerException exc){

                        }

                           try {
                            URL reqURL = new URL(url);
                            URLConnection connection = null;
                            if(local){
                                connection = reqURL.openConnection();
                            }
                            else {
                                connection = reqURL.openConnection(proxy);
                            }
                            connection.setDoInput(true);
                            connection.setDoOutput(false);

                            InputStream is = null;
                            is = connection.getInputStream();

                             byte by[] = new byte[ BUFFER_SIZE ];
                             int index = is.read( by, 0, BUFFER_SIZE );

                                while ( index != -1 ){
                                  clientout.write( by, 0, index );
                                  index = is.read( by, 0, BUFFER_SIZE );
                                }

                                clientout.flush();

                           }catch(Exception ex){

                           }

                          try {
                            clientin.close();
                            clientout.close();
                        //  client.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                }
    }   

}
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the empty catch blocks and someone might help you.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.
You have to add the following to `URLConnection`

```
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0; H010818)");
```